# command not found

Tags: bash, shell-script

Mais uma dúvida de novato

```
echo "Enter an integer number"
read int
checkNum=$(( int % 2 ))

if [$checkNum -eq '0' ]; then

 echo "the number is even"
else
  echo "the number is odd"
fi
```

Erro quando digito qualquer número:

> ./test4.sh: line 9: [0: command not found
>   the number is odd

Comment: Acho que você esqueceu o espaçamento no seu if, o correto seria `if [ $checkNum -eq '0' ]; then`

Comment: Funcionou!!! Obrigado... ate me acertar com esses espaços....